# Generate and store Excel (.xls) file in MySQL database possible?

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I am looking for a way that will allow me to generate an Excel file through a web application (website will be built through SpringBoot MVC) which generates an Excel file containing random numbers, which is then stored as an entry in a SQL table, along with some other values next to it.

My main concern is the storing into SQL part, which I can't find a way to do other than generating the data into a table which is stored in a cell in another table's row, and whenever the Excel file is requested downloaded, it reads the SQL table data and generates an Excel file like that... Right? Or is there some framework, or perhaps another nice Java compatible database that allows me to save .xls files directly into it's cells?

Any other tips will be appreciated as well!

Comment: Just store the binary file representation in a column with datatype [`BLOB`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/blob.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem 1 - storing Excel files in the database:

In your database table create a new field with binary data type. Then you can store your Excel file as raw bytes.

Problem 2 - working with SQL in Java:

I recommend checking out jOOQ (https://www.jooq.org/). It will allow you to create an object model of the database and write type safe queries against it. Well worth the time investment to learn.

Comment: Thanks! I will check out jOOQ for sure.